# Set next element value based on clicked element value using jquery (or javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input, first is checkbox and the other is input hidden. I also have multiple input on 1 page

```
<input type="checkbox" class="comp-checkk" value="45164c0b-fc92-4f93-9c62-ea61336130eb">
<input type="hidden" class="comp-id" name="component_id[]" value="45164c0b-fc92-4f93-9c62-ea61336130eb"> 

<input type="checkbox" class="comp-checkk" value="45164c0b-fc92-4f93-9c62-ea61336130eb">
<input type="hidden" class="comp-id" name="component_id[]">

<input type="checkbox" class="comp-checkk" value="45164c0b-fc92-4f93-9c62-ea61336130eb">
<input type="hidden" class="comp-id" name="component_id[]">
```

I want to set the value of input with `comp-id` class using value from `comp-checkk` class value. And if the value of `comp-id` is not null, I want to set `comp-id` to null, else if the value of `comp-id` is null, I want to set `comp-id` value with value from `comp-check`

I've tried like this:

```
$(document).on('change','.comp-checkk',function(){
    if ($(this).next().val() != null) {
       $(this).next().val(null);
    } else {
       $(this).next().val($(this).val());
    }
});
```

It's working if the `comp-id` is not null, but when the value is null it's not working (nothing happened). I don't know what is wrong with my code.

[I also made JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2L6psxgr/)

Comment: have you tried checking the value of $(this).val() in console? does it output anything?

Comment: @Mashtan I got the value from `comp-checkk` input

Comment: Update your if condition as `if ($(this).next().val() != null && $(this).next().val() != "") { ... .}`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not adding any value to community. OP's problem was fixed and answer is provided in comment itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for both **not null** and also for **not empty**

```
if ($(this).next().val() != null && $(this).next().val() != '') {
   $(this).next().val(null);
} else {
   $(this).next().val($(this).val());
}
```